# Strange behaviour of Interaction Graph in Orange

Tags: orange

I am new to Orange and I am trying to make an "Interaction Graph" in orange. When I try it with iris.tab example from orange web site the graph works fine.

I have made a tab file with my data and I get some strange behaviour. It is connected to unselected attributes. First, the selected attributes list is not correct. Second, when I click on an attribute in the graph, some other attribute is shown in unselected attributes. I would have attached a picture if I was allowed to. I selected ModeSAddress and WeekDayOfFlight is displayed in unselected attributes list. It works like this for all attributes. For any attribute I select some other attribute is displayed in the unselected attributes list.

Since this feature does not work I cannot be sure the Interaction Graph is correct. What can I do?

I am using Orange 2.7 in Ubuntu 64bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is (was) an error in Orange. It is now fixed in the master development branch.